# is it possible to set a default value for a msbuild / visual studio property sheet

Tags: msbuild

I am creating a new build step with a separate task. The schema for the `BoolProperty` `StringProperty` includes a `Default`, but there seems no way to get VS(2017) to apply the default value, when the user has not chosen an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit the (default) values from .props file. Create a file and named it as Directory.Build.props in your project folder.

For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017